# The Meaning of "call for sb to do sth"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I ran into an unfamiliar phrase in a [news article](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-australia-56163550)

> They have also faced increased scrutiny over their power, including "calls **for** them to do" more to combat misinformation and abuse.

I know "call **on** sb to do sth" means ["to ask someone in a formal way to do something"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/call-on-sb-to-do-sth).
Does this have a same meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 'call' is a request, or a demand.

The preposition that follows (*on, for, to* etc) depends on whether you are introducing the details of the request, or the individual or group you are making the request to.

For example:

- Calls *for* better healthcare have been directed at the government.
- Many are calling *on* the government for better healthcare.
- There are calls *for* the government *to* provide better healthcare.

Comment: I realy appreciate your swift answer. I did not notice "call" is noun.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Learner-Koara It can be a noun or a verb. For example, 'a phone call' is a noun, but the action of making a phone call is 'to call' or 'calling'.